# Why can't my produce complete the flush method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

My program is stuck in produce.flush and there is no corresponding message in the confluent control center.

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer

p = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': '47.75.57.41:9092'})
p.produce('echo_topic', 'echo_message'.encode('utf-8'))
print('start flush')
p.flush()
print('finish flush')
```

[Control Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar6PS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to set KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092 for the host network